# Вернуть запятые целым числам с помощью PHP

Tags: php, функции

Через API получаю массив данных. В них есть цена товара и она почему то приходит без запятых. Например приходит 1454, а должно быть 14,54. Приходит 65, а должно быть 0,65. Никакие PHP функции, которые мне бы подошли не нашел. Каким образом с помощью php можно вернуть запятую обратно в эти числа?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно просто разделить входящее число на 100. Если нужно отформатировать до двух знаков после запятой

```
 sprintf('%0.2f', $num/100);
```

Comment: Сделал. Просто добавилось к числу точка и два нуля. Было 1454, стало 1454.00.

Comment: забыл разделить на 100. Исправил

Comment: Теперь да. Все четко. Спасибо большое. Блин, все гениально и просто. Просто на 100 поделить. А то я уже думал какие то функции надо писать.

Comment: @Alines, если вопрос решил вашу проблему, вы можете отблагодарить автора выбрав его ответ как правильный, галочка слева от ответа.